# Javascript search form doesn't work in Firefox, but does in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox

I have a js script which searches a database and on selection inserts a value into the search form. That all works fine. But on clicking submit on the form, only in IE does it do what it is supposed to go to clientdetails.php using GET method using the submitted value. in Firefox, nothing happens.

```js
$(function() {
 $( "#clientsearch" ).autocomplete({
  source: 'backend_search_address2.php'
 });
});
```

```html
<form action="clientdetails.php" method = "get" role="form" style = "padding-top: 7%">
   <div class="form-group input-group">
      <input id= "clientsearch" type="text" name="client_id" class="form-control" placeholder="Search by address...">
           <span class="input-group-btn">
           <button type="submit" value="Submit" form="clientsearch" class="btn btn-default" role="button"></a><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
           </button>
           </span>
   </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Are there any errors in browser developer console? For FF, try using FireBug - https://addons.mozilla.org/ru/firefox/addon/firebug/

Comment: why you used `</a>` in between?

Comment: @t1gor why firebug if a simple console ( `F12`) is sufficient. @OP: Please check your HTML first. What's that `</a>` doing there ?

Comment: Make a snippet , verify before ask :)

Comment: Please include the jquery.min.js file for this error : Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined"                                                    
 <head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

Comment: @Deepa I guess it's safe to assume that OP included jQuery in his actual code. *@OP* Your button has `form="clientsearch"`; removing that makes it work on Firefox.

Comment: @ChrisG this worked

Comment: @ChrisG : i tried to run OP's code snippet it showed that error, so i mentioned that for that error this the solution.

Comment: @Deepa Ok, but that error was introduced by turning the code into a runnable snippet but not including jQuery. If that had been the error, the form wouldn't have worked in any browser. OP already confirmed what the error was anyway.

Comment: @ChrisG : Oh Ok. Thanks!